# How to get selected text from an Outlook received email using in VSTO C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I get emails with 2 important pieces of information within the body that the information is not always in the same place.  The first set of text is an email address and the second set is an error or reason.  I would like to create a custom button on the ribbon where I can get those two pieces of information easily and then do something with them.  This is what I am thinking of doing:

1. Highlight email address
2. Click button 1
3. Highlight error/reason
4. Click button 2
5. Click button 3 and do something with those results.

I can't find examples online on how to copy those two fields to some hidden form for steps 2 and 3 of clicking buttons 1 and 2.

I haven't tried much because I can't find how to even extract selected text within an email body.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

PreviewPane is available in outlook 2016 and above version [PreviewPane detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.previewpane). If you need selected text from the preview pane, use following code in VBA.

```
Application.ActiveExplorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text
```

If the text is selected in an `Inspector`, use

```
Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text
```

Keep in mind that `ActiveExplorer` and `ActiveInspector` are functions, not properties, so `()` are needed in C#.

Comment: Above code is not wroking and not available . ActiveExplorer is function not property.

Comment: The above example is VBA, not C#. If you want C#, use `Application.ActiveExplorer().PreviewPane.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text` and `Application.ActiveInspector().WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text`